# How can I use IFS for seperator to join a subset of an array in Bash's here document?

Tags: arrays, bash, heredoc, ifs

I have an array, and I would like to concatenate a subset of it, passing it along with some text as stdin for other commands to use.

This works in here string but not in here document, even the same code:

```bash
declare -a arr=(12 34 56 78 90)
IFS=','

# join a subset of arr by IFS in here string (OK)
cat <<<"${arr[*]:0:3}"

# doesn't work in here doc, all commas are gone. unless joining all elements
cat <<EOF
${arr[*]:0:3}
${arr[*]}
EOF
```

output:

```
12,34,56
12 34 56
12,34,56,78,90
```

Comment: When I run your test script on my CentOS 7 system, it works perfectly the way you want it too.  GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Works with 4.0.33; fails with 5.0.17. Possibly a bug.